# Oozie shell script job

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform, oozie-coordinator

I have one shell script script.sh, which needs one property file script.properties.

I executed this script as:
./script.sh script.properties

Now I want to run this script using oozie.

How can I pass the script.properties file to the script.sh.

Answer (score 0):

copy the property file in same hdfs path as script.sh and add as `<file>[FILE-PATH]</file>` in workflow.xml .

check this link for shell action example http://rogerhosto.com/apache-oozie-shell-script-example/